# Geodjango Import Shapefile with LayerMapping and OGR

Tags: python, django, geodjango, ogr

I am trying to load a shapefile into Django

My folder

```
vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.dbf
vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.prj
vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.qpj
vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp
vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shx
```

When I'm running this:

```
simon@DESKTOP-V82N14G:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/poc_dashboard/pocdash$  ogrinfo -ro -so  testdjango/data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp
INFO: Open of `testdjango/data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc (Polygon)
```

When I use the python shell to run my code:

```
python manage.py shell
from testdjango import load_layer
load_layer.run()
```

It returns me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/poc_dashboard/pocdash/testdjango/load_layer.py", line 27, in run
    lm = LayerMapping(Adm3_names, adm3_name_shp, adm3_name_mapping, transform= False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
  File "/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/poc_dashboard/poc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.ds = DataSource(data, encoding=encoding)
  File "/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/poc_dashboard/poc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 74, in __init__
    raise GDALException('Could not open the datasource at "%s"' % ds_input)
django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Could not open the datasource at "/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/poc_dashboard/pocdash/testdjango/testdjango/data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp"
```

Is it something wrong with my code or something wrong with my shapefile? I attached the file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EknCMi1r7AGmauiDNuVC3e8NARvsHXGc)

```
import os
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from .models import Adm3_names

adm3_name_mapping = {
    'gid': 'gid',
    'adm1_code': 'adm1_code',
    'adm1_name': 'adm1_name',
    'adm2_code': 'adm2_code',
    'adm2_name': 'adm2_name',
    'adm3_code': 'adm3_code',
    'adm3_name': 'adm3_name',
    'adm3_statu': 'adm3_statu',
    'pop': 'pop',
    'pop_0to14': 'pop_0to14',
    'pop_65plus': 'pop_65plus',
    'hh': 'hh',
    'shape_leng': 'shape_leng',
    'shape_area': 'shape_area',
    'geom': 'MULTIPOLYGON',
}

adm3_name_shp = os.path. abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'testdjango/data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp'))

def run(verbose=True):
    lm = LayerMapping(Adm3_names, adm3_name_shp, adm3_name_mapping, transform= False, encoding='iso-8859-1')
    lm.save(strict=True,verbose=verbose)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/

Comment: Are you sure this path is correct: `django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: Could not open the datasource at "/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/poc_dashboard/pocdash/testdjango/testdjango/data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp`? Because I see the `testdjango` repeating 2 times.

Comment: Thanls yes... should have keep a eye open! Thanks Usman !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out from the comments, the problem was the creation of the `adm3_name_shp` which adds an extra `testdjango` folder to the path:

Change this:

```
adm3_name_shp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'testdjango/data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp'))
```

to this:

```
adm3_name_shp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'data/vnm_polbn_adm3_2014_pdc.shp'))
```

Another tip you should consider is that the `os.path.abspath` calls the [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) in the background and that is what transforms your path to the correct OS path (either with `\` for Windows or `/` for Linux etc.):

> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references so that `A//B`, `A/B/`, `A/./B` and `A/foo/../B` all become `A/B`. This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that contains symbolic links. **On Windows, it converts forward slashes to backward slashes.** To normalize case, use normcase().

So you can replace the `abspath` with `normpath` but this is optional.

Comment: Thanks @John Moutafis for the tips! Will remember ;)

Comment: @SimonGIS Happy to help :)